# How to Convert TimeZone in to CountryName or in CountryCode - Python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, timezone

Is there any option better and faster than this code below that I am using to get the name of the Country from the name of a City! So I'm trying to get for example from a Timezone (Europe/Istanbul) to get in the end Turkey/TR or to convert a Timezone (Europe/Berlin) to a Country Code (DE) and after from the (DE) to convert to Germany/DE, so all I want is... no matter which `TIMEZONE` will be, at the end to give me always `FLAG/COUNTRY/CODE`

This code I'm using is 60% okay and slow, but every time when it's London in TIMEZONE I get `NONE` results, also I'm getting `NONE` results from some others TIMEZONE, not only if it's London!

```
import pycountry
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

#Example:
timezone='Europe/London'

try:
    city=str(timezone).split('/')[1].replace('/','')
except:pass

vpzip(city)
    coun=""
    code=""
    flag=""
    country=""
    try:
        geolocator=Nominatim(user_agent="location-finder",timeout=3)
        location=geolocator.geocode(city, language='en')
        countrys=str(location).split(',')[-1].replace(' ','')
        countr=pycountry.countries.get(name=countrys)
        code=countr.alpha_2
        flag=countr.flag
        coun=countr.name
        country=str(flag)+'/'+str(coun)+'/'+str(code)
    except:
        country='NONE'
    return country

print(vpzip(city))
```

Thanks in advance to ALL

Answer (score 3):

It probably doesn't help but if you use Pandas, it can be possible to make the mapping yourself:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones')[0].iloc[:, :2]
df1.columns = ['Code', 'Timezone']
df1 = df1.assign(Code=df1['Code'].str.split(',\s*')).explode('Code').dropna()

df2 = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_indicator_symbol')[0].iloc[:, :3]
df2.columns = ['Flag', 'Code', 'Country']

out = df1.merge(df2, on='Code')
```

```
>>> out
    Code            Timezone Flag           Country
0     CI      Africa/Abidjan        Côte d'Ivoire
1     BF      Africa/Abidjan         Burkina Faso
2     BF  Africa/Ouagadougou         Burkina Faso
3     GH      Africa/Abidjan                Ghana
4     GH        Africa/Accra                Ghana
..   ...                 ...  ...               ...
646   PN    Pacific/Pitcairn     Pitcairn Islands
647   CK   Pacific/Rarotonga         Cook Islands
648   WF      Pacific/Tarawa      Wallis & Futuna
649   WF      Pacific/Wallis      Wallis & Futuna
650   TO   Pacific/Tongatapu                Tonga

[651 rows x 4 columns]
```

Test:

```
>>> out[out['Timezone']=='Europe/London']
    Code       Timezone Flag         Country
525   GB  Europe/London     United Kingdom
559   GG  Europe/London           Guernsey
564   IM  Europe/London        Isle of Man
566   JE  Europe/London             Jersey
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a faster performing code use `countrywrangler` instead of `pycountry`.

Here is a usage example:

```py
import countrywrangler as cw

timezone='Europe/London'

country_code = cw.Normalize.timezone_to_alpha2(timezone)

print(country_code) # Prints GB
```

Full documentation: https://countrywrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/normalize/timezone/

Disclosure: I am the author of countrywrangler.

Comment: /data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py:11: UserWarning: Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning
  warnings.warn('Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning') I Have this Warning after I installed the countrywrangler modul!